# Example of an integral not converging

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, examples-counterexamples, lebesgue-integral, uniform-convergence

> > Consider a measurable space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ with $\mu(\Omega)<\infty$. Let $f_1,f_2,\ldots$ be bounded measurable functions so, that $f_n\to f$ uniformly. Then $f$ is measurable and integrable and $\int f_n\, d\mu\to\int f\, d\mu$.
> >     Find an example that shows that the condition $\mu(\Omega)<\infty$ is necessary.

Hello, I already proved the claim, but I did not find a counterexample yet that shows, that $\mu(\Omega)<\infty$ cannot be neglected.

Can you help me to find one?

My first idea was to consider $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B},\lambda)$, where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue-measure. Anyway, it is $\lambda(\mathbb{R})=\infty$.

Comment: what about $f_n=\frac{1}{n}$ on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B},\lambda)$.

Comment: if you've proved the claim, just see when you use the fact that $\mu(\Omega) < \infty$ and it won't be too difficult to find a counterexample

Comment: Please make the title more specific. In the future, please do not put things like "measure theory" in the title—those belong only in the tags unless you're asking a question about measure theory itself as opposed to a question within it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take on the measure space you suggest $f_n(x):=\frac 1n\chi_{(0,n)}$.

Comment: Then $f_n\to 0=:f$ uniformly for $n\to\infty$. But $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_n\, d\mu=1$ and this does not converge to $\int _{\mathbb{R}}f\, d\mu=0$. But where does appear significantly the fact, that $\lambda(\mathbb{R})=\infty$?

Comment: When the measure is finite, everything is controlled by the uniform convergence. But when the measure is infinite, we can have functions very small on a set of  very large measure.

Answer (score 4):

On the real line, how about this: $$f_n(x)=\frac{\chi_{[-n,n]}(x)}{1+|x|}$$

Comment: To be clear, my answer is a counterexample to $f$ being integrable. The answer by @Davide is a counterexample to the convergence of the integral.

Comment: What I see is, that $f_n\to f:=\frac{1}{1+\lvert x\rvert}$ uniformly and that $f_n$ are measurable and bounded. But why is f not integrable?

Comment: Just try integrating it, from $0$ to $\infty$ (so you can get rid of the absolute value). You find that the indefinite integral for $x>0$ is $\ln(1+x)$, right?